# ASP.NET if what the session has stored is.. Then

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a small bit of code right now but can't figure it out.
So far we have a working login page, the login page remembers the username via a session, drags it over to the main page, where it is displayed with a simple hello message.

For this project different users need to have different permissions, user 1 can see A, bot not B, user 2 can't see A but can see B etc.

I've tried looking for more accesible ways to do this, but unfortunately time is ticking.

My idea was to create an if statement that caled upon the username in the home page. If the user name is User1, hide lbl_b etc.

```
string NaamG = Convert.ToString(Session["GNaamp"]);

if (NaamG.Text = "User1")
{

}
```

This is the small part I have right now. Gnaam being the session that carries over the username.

Hope my question is clear, thanks in advance!

Comment: Is something not working? That part isn't clear.

Comment: I take the question to be about whether the approach is viable or, if not, what approach might be better. That's a valid question IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common and well-supported way to handle that type of security requirement is to assign users to roles and render the UI based on whether the logged-in user has the required role (also enforce the role requirement on the back end e.g. in controllers/controller actions following the security truism "never trust the UI"). This is known as [role-based security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

If that's not an option in your case, you can certainly create a "lite" version for your project. For example, you could make a list of user names that are allowed to do "A", a separate list for users allowed to do "B", etc. Your UI rendering code could then look something like

```
List<string> usesrssAllowedToDoA = new List<string>()
{
    "User1", "User42"
};
if (usersAllowedToDoA.Contains(NaamG))
{
    ... do stuff
}
```

Comment: I've indeed seen Role-based security. It's however not someting we've covered and parts of our database are still changing right now. This however worked like a charm! Thank you so much!